# How to check if a button is pressed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bloc

I need a like button , when you click it once , the number will increase , but when you click it second time , the number will decrease, how to check if the button is clicked

This is my customer flutter widget exercise

the button widget

```
lass ButtonBuilder extends StatefulWidget{
  final Icon icon;

  ButtonBuilder({this.icon,});

  _ButtonBuilderState createState()=>_ButtonBuilderState(this.icon);
}

class _ButtonBuilderState extends State<ButtonBuilder>{
  final Icon _icon;

   _ButtonBuilderState(this._icon);

  final _bloc=ButtonCounterBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RootButton(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _bloc.counter,
        initialData: 0,
        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          return _buildButton(_icon,'${snapshot.data}');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildButton(Icon _icon,String _text){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: _icon,
          onPressed: ()=>_bloc.buttonEventSink.add(FirstOnPressedEvent()),
        ),
        Text(_text),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

the main.dart

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ButtonBuilder(icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),),
            ButtonBuilder(icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_down),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i don't know how to check if the button is clicked

Comment: simply use a boolean variable initialy false once pressed make it true when again pressing check if its already true then ake it false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a flag called `isPressed` initially set to `false`, which is negated everytime the button is pressed.

And inside the `onPressed` callback, you can write different logic depending on the variable.

But you should keep in mind that in the example below, the `_isPressed` variable will be reset once the `State` for the button widet is disposed.

If you wish to have a persistent button, you can add a similar parameter inside `ButtonCounterBloc` and assign it's value to `_isPressed` inside the `initState` method for the `_ButtonBuilderState` class.

That way your button will be persistent even if the app is restarted or the state is disposed and mounted again.

```
class ButtonBuilder extends StatefulWidget{
  final Icon icon;

  ButtonBuilder({this.icon,});

  _ButtonBuilderState createState()=>_ButtonBuilderState(this.icon);
}

class _ButtonBuilderState extends State<ButtonBuilder>{
  final Icon _icon;

   _ButtonBuilderState(this._icon);

  final _bloc=ButtonCounterBloc();
  bool _isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RootButton(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _bloc.counter,
        initialData: 0,
        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          return _buildButton(_icon,'${snapshot.data}');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildButton(Icon _icon,String _text){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: _icon,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isPressed = !_isPressed;
            });
            if(_isPressed) {
              // This block will be executed when button is pressed odd number of times.
              _bloc.buttonEventSink.add(FirstOnPressedEvent());
            } else {
              // This block will be executed when button is pressed even number of times;
            }
          }
        ),
        Text(_text),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```